# What are these HUD symbols?

Tags: resident-evil-6

I know the big white blocks are "health" that can regenerate if partially damaged, the RB is for restoring health blocks with herbs, and the bottom red is the ammo indicator, but what are those white bars in the middle? I thought it was stamina, but it doesn't deplete when I run. The only time I've seen it go down is after a cutscene where I'm hurt and require a few seconds for recovery (where those white bars restore). What are they, and how do they affect me? And do the other "dots" in the HUD/UI signify anything, or are they only there for decoration?

[image: HUD]

<sup>Sorry for the terrible screenshot</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The smaller white blocks *are* your stamina. They only deplete when using melee attacks (and quite possible only when they connect?), including counter attacks.

Essentially they limit how much ammo you can save by beating zombies to death!